# Summing keys and values in a list of dictionaries python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a list of dictionaries called "timebucket" :

```
[{0.9711533363722904: 0.008296776727415599}, 
 {0.97163564816067838: 0.008153794130319884}, 
 {0.99212783984967068: 0.0022392112909864364}, 
 {0.98955473263127025: 0.0029843621053514003}]
```

I would like to return the top two largest keys (.99 and .98) and average them , plus , get both of their values and average those as well.

Expected output would like something like:

```
 { (avg. two largest keys) : (avg. values of two largest keys) }
```

I've tried:

```
import numpy as np
import heapq
[np.mean(heapq.nlargest(2, i.keys())) for i in timebucket]
```

but heapq doesn't work in this scenario, and not sure how to keep keys and values linked

Comment: `heapq` mutates in place, so you need a variable. Do all the `dict`s just have one item in them? Any reason they aren't tuples?

Comment: they come from a defaultdict(list)

Comment: that didnt really make a difference, but basically i have a bunch of these lists in one bigger one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this with `numpy`:

```
In []:
a = np.array([e for i in timebucket for e in i.items()]); 
a[a[:,1].argsort()][:2].mean(axis=0)

Out[]
array([ 0.99084129,  0.00261179])
```

Though I suspect creating a better data-structure up front would probably be a better approach.

Comment: where is i.items coming from?

Comment: `i` is coming from `for i in timebucket`, so `i` is a `dict`, `i.items()` returns the dict as list of tuples which is flattened so turns the list of dicts to a list of tuples, e.g. `[{x0:y0}, {x1:y1}, ...]` to `[(x0,y0), (x1,y1), ...]` which `numpy` can directly operate on.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the average of 2 largest keys (keyave) and the average of the two corresponding values (valave).
The keys and values are put into a dictionary called newdict.

```
timebucket = [{0.9711533363722904: 0.008296776727415599}, 
 {0.97163564816067838: 0.008153794130319884}, 
 {0.99212783984967068: 0.0022392112909864364}, 
 {0.98955473263127025: 0.0029843621053514003}]
keys = []
for time in timebucket:
  for x in time:
    keys.append(x)
result = {}
for d in timebucket:
   result.update(d)


largestkey = (sorted(keys)[-1])
ndlargestkey = (sorted(keys)[-2])
keyave = (float((largestkey)+(ndlargestkey))/2)

largestvalue = (result[(largestkey)])
ndlargestvalue = (result[(ndlargestkey)])
valave = (float((largestvalue)+(ndlargestvalue))/2)
newdict = {}
newdict[keyave] = valave

print(newdict)
#print(keyave)
#print(valave)
```

Output
`{0.9908412862404705: 0.002611786698168918}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to your problem:

```
def dothisthing(mydict) # define the function with a dictionary a the only parameter
    keylist = [] # create an empty list
    for key in mydict: # iterate the input dictionary
        keylist.append(key) # add the key from the dictionary to a list
    keylist.sort(reverse = True) # sort the list  from highest to lowest numbers
    toptwokeys = 0 # create a variable
    toptwovals = 0 # create a variable
    count = 0 # create an integer variable
    for item in keylist: # iterate the list we created above
        if count <2: # this limits the iterations to the first 2 
            toptwokeys += item # add the key 
            toptwovals += (mydict[item]) # add the value
        count += 1
    finaldict = {(toptwokeys/2):(toptwovals/2)} # create a dictionary where the key and val are the average of the 2 from the input dict with the greatest keys
    return finaldict # return the output dictionary

dothisthing({0.9711533363722904: 0.008296776727415599, 0.97163564816067838: 0.008153794130319884, 0.99212783984967068: 0.0022392112909864364, 0.98955473263127025: 0.0029843621053514003})
#call the function with your dictionary as the parameter
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in just four lines without importing numpy :

> ### One line solution
>
> For two max average keys :

```
max_keys_average=sorted([keys for item in timebucket for keys,values in item.items()])[::-1][:2]


print(sum(max_keys_average)/len(max_keys_average))
```

output:

```
0.9908412862404705
```

> for their keys average :

```
max_values_average=[values for item in max_keys_average for item_1 in timebucket for keys,values in item_1.items() if item==keys]

print(sum(max_values_average)/len(max_values_average))
```

output:

```
0.002611786698168918
```

> If you are facing issue with understanding  list comprehension here is detailed solution for you:
>
> ### Detailed Solution

first step:

get all the keys of dict in one list :

```
Here is your timebucket list:

timebucket=[{0.9711533363722904: 0.008296776727415599},
 {0.97163564816067838: 0.008153794130319884},
 {0.99212783984967068: 0.0022392112909864364},
 {0.98955473263127025: 0.0029843621053514003}]
```

now let's store all the keys in one list:

```
keys_list=[]

for dict in timebucket:
    for key,value in dict.items():
        keys_list.append(key)
```

Now next step is sort this list and get last two values of this list :

```
max_keys=sorted(keys_list)[::-1][:2]
```

Next step just take sum of this new list and divide by len of list :

```
print(sum(max_keys)/len(max_keys))
```

output:

```
0.9908412862404705
```

Now just iterate the max_keys and keys in timebucket and see if both item match then get the value of that item in a list.

```
max_values=[]

for item in max_keys:
    for dict in timebucket:
        for key, value in dict.items():
            if item==key:
                max_values.append(value)

print(max_values)
```

Now last part , just take sum and divide by len of max_values:

```
print(sum(max_values)/len(max_values))
```

Gives the output :

```
0.002611786698168918
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative solution to the problem:

```
In []:
import numpy as np
import time

def AverageTB(time_bucket):
    tuples = [tb.items() for tb in time_bucket]
    largest_keys = []
    largest_keys.append(max(tuples))
    tuples.remove(max(tuples))
    largest_keys.append(max(tuples))
    keys = [i[0][0] for i in largest_keys]
    values = [i[0][1] for i in largest_keys]
    return np.average(keys), np.average(values)

time_bucket = [{0.9711533363722904: 0.008296776727415599},
           {0.97163564816067838: 0.008153794130319884},
           {0.99212783984967068: 0.0022392112909864364},
           {0.98955473263127025: 0.0029843621053514003}]
time_exe = time.time()
print('avg. (keys, values): {}'.format(AverageTB(time_bucket)))
print('time: {}'.format(time.time() - time_exe))


Out[]:
avg. (keys, values): (0.99084128624047052, 0.0026117866981689181)
time: 0.00037789344787
```

Comment: Hi Jagh. Welcome to SO! It might be a good idea to explain why your solution works, so that newcomers to the language and ideas you have used can understand why you did what you did and why it works.